# Do asymptotic analysis for the following problem,

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, asymptotics

I have an ordinary differential equation,
$-\rho \frac{d\theta}{d\rho}=\frac{d}{d\rho}\left(\frac{\alpha^2}{(\beta+\theta)^2}\frac{d\theta}{d\rho}\right),$ where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are parameters. How to do asymptotic analysis for $\theta(\rho)=\rho^{-a}(\log(\rho))^{b}$.

Comment: own thoughts???

Comment: Asymptotic analysis in what sense?

Comment: Leading order behavior